# how to build a differential system that has a specified invariant curve?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I would like to build a system of differential equations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that has a set of pre-determined invariant curves. For instance, given the three following functions
\begin{equation}
g_1(x.y)=x\qquad g_2(x,y)=y\qquad g_3(x,y)=x-1
\end{equation}
I'd like the system to have $g_1=0,g_2=0$ and $g_3=0$ as invariant curves (lines, in this case).

If the system is given by
\begin{equation}
(\dot{x},\dot{y})=F(x,y)
\end{equation}
I thought that the condition to set had to be
\begin{equation}
\nabla g_i(x,y)\cdot F(x,y)=0\qquad i=1,2,3
\end{equation}
but I'm not sure as these conditions yield unreasonable constraints...any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you have vector function $\boldsymbol f$ and scalar function $g$, then
$$
\boldsymbol F = (\boldsymbol \nabla g)^2\boldsymbol f-(\boldsymbol f\boldsymbol \nabla g)\boldsymbol\nabla g
$$
will be always collinear with vector field $\boldsymbol\nabla g$.

This gives us a hint how to build what you want. For some arbitrary functions $\boldsymbol f_i$:
$$
F = \left(\boldsymbol f_0+\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{
(\boldsymbol\nabla g_i)^2\boldsymbol f_i-(\boldsymbol f_i\boldsymbol\nabla g_i)\boldsymbol\nabla g_i
}{g_i}\right)g_1g_2g_3.
$$

For example, for $f_0=f_1=f_2=f_3=(x^2-y^2,x+y)$ and your $g_i$:
$$
F=\left(x(x-1) (y+1) \left(x^2-y^2\right),\left(x^2+x-1\right) y (x+y)\right)
$$
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you please explain what you mean with $(\nabla g)^2$?

Comment: $(\nabla g)^2 = g_x'^2+g_y'^2$

Comment: Thanks! Why the multiplication by $g_1,g_2,g_3$? It seems that doing so all the points in those curves are fixed points, or am I wrong?

Comment: If you could make the details of your solution a bit more explicit I'd be happy to mark yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: And I believe that you meant "orthogonal" instead of "collinear"?

Comment: When you multiply 1st term on $g_1g_2g_3$, $g_1$ will cancel out. So only first term will be non-zero when $g_1=0$.