# Invariant curve of a differential system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I wanted to ask for the specific definition of an "invariant curve" of a DS or a book where I could find it. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "differential system", maybe you mean "dynamical system" related to an ODE or PDE. However this might help with a general idea https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/First_integral

Comment: A system of ODE's

Comment: related to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978885/how-to-build-a-differential-system-that-has-a-specified-invariant-curve

Comment: It is a curve such that for any initial condition on the curve the corresponding solution remains in the curve for all times (in its domain of definition). Note that invariant curve are rare in nonautonomous systems.